# how do i delete particular item from model with mongoose in my todolist app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I want to delete a item when delete button is pressed. How do i delete that particular item is their any wat to pass a value to server side with help of button as button is pressed
here is list.ejs code:

```
<%for(let i=0;i<itemslist.length;i++){%>
  <li> <%=itemslist[i].item%> </li>
  <% var ind=i%>
  <form action="/delete" method="POST"><button value="">Delete</button></form>  
  <form action="/edit" method="POST"><button onclick="editfunc()" >Edit</button></form>      
<%}%>
```

while here is my server side code app.js

```
 app.post("/delete",function(req,res){
    Item.deleteOne({},function())
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete one expects a query and you're passing in an empty object.

---

Modify your ejs to bind the current item as a data attribute to the current list item which is a form.

```
<%for(let i=0;i<itemslist.length;i++){%>
  <li> <%=itemslist[i].item%> </li>
  <% var ind=i%>
  <form action="/delete" method="POST" class="delete-item" data-item=`${itemslist[i].item}`><button value="">Delete</button></form>  
  <form action="/edit" method="POST"><button onclick="editfunc()" >Edit</button></form>      
<%}%>
```

In your front end script add an event handler to listen on submit events for the delete form, here extract the item from the data attribute and send it to your API -

```
$(document).on('submit', '.delete-item', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var item = JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-item'));
    var successCb = function(data) {
        console.log('Deleted item - ', item);
    };
    
    var errorCb = function(error) {
        console.error(error && error.responseJSON);
    };
    
    $.post('/delete', {
        item
    }).done(successCb)
    .fail(errorCb);
    
});
```

In your server-side, use the mongoose function [`deleteOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-deleteOne) to delete a particular item -

```
app.post("/delete", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const { item } = req.body;
        await Item.deleteOne({ item });
        res.redirect("/");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```